# how i get the maven compilation number of projects

Tags: maven, terminal

[image]

you see in image ahter 1.0 SNAPSHOT there is Number like [2/67] hoi get these number to it is better to get number of projects during compilaton
i get these on my terminal but i dont know hot they dissappered.So,can anybody help me how i get back again on my teminal

i tried to get on the maven option 
mvn --
--activate-profiles         --encrypt-master-password   --global-settings           --projects                  --update-plugins 
--also-make                 --encrypt-password          --help                      --quiet                     --update-snapshots 
--also-make-dependents      --errors                    --lax-checksums             --reactor                   --version 
--batch-mode                --fail-at-end               --non-recursive             --resume-from
--check-plugin-updates      --fail-fast                 --no-plugin-registry        --settings
--debug                     --fail-never                --no-plugin-updates         --show-version
--define                    --file                      --offline                   --strict-checksums

but i dont get it please tell me

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you please state exactly what you like to do and what you have tried so far?

Comment: in image you see the number after 1.0 SNAPSHOT [2/67] i want those number because it indicates the process of completed compilation i got that number when i update my OS but suddenly they get disappeared so what i do for show these number on terminal while compilation

Comment: Are you talking about this `[2/67]`?

Comment: yes i want these numbers so i get the progress status of compilation

Comment: In which circumstances do you need that? Apart from that this will only work if you don't use parallel build...

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: i am not using parallel build functionality,